# "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module" when importing WooCommerce API node module

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

I have a noobie question. Please be kind.

I am using this PHP function to import my custom JavaScript:

```
public function my_load_scripts() {
        wp_register_script(
            'custom_js_one',
            plugins_url( 'js/demo-one.js', __FILE__ ),
            '', '',
            true
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js_one');
}
```

... and right now that custom JavaScript does virtually nothing:

```
import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api";

alert('Hello!');
```

Now I run into the problem. The script tag that WordPress generates is not defined as a module (via `type="module"` in the `<script>` tag), so I get "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module" in my console.

**Is there any way to tell WordPress to treat my registered script as a separate tag with that necessary `type="module"` attribute so that I can import other modules?**

(Note that I realize I'll still need to register those other modules in my PHP function, as they won't otherwise be accessible to the front end.)

Comment: Same problem with Prestashop, script tag are generated with type="text/javascript" even if type="module" is written in the <script> tag.